# Push onto array with loop in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have the following code, which is the answer to my earlier question: [Looping through 2d Typescript array and making new array from value at index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741426/looping-through-2d-typescript-array-and-making-new-array-from-value-at-index/45746574?noredirect=1#comment78471841_45746574) if only it worked. I thought I would repost because otherwise the orig. post would get too complicated.

I don't understand why I can't seem to push to an array, or access the array outside the loop?

```
  this.days_in_month = [
    [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31], [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31], [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31], [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31], 
  ];

  this.month_weekdays = [];
  this.days_in_month.forEach(function each(item) {
      // console.log(item);
      item.forEach(function each(value){
        // console.log(value);

        let thing: number = value;
          for(var i = 0; i < thing; i++) {
            let weekdays: string[] = [ 'M','T','W','T','F','S','S' ];
            let wkday: string = (weekdays[(i%7)]);
            this.month_weekdays.push(wkday);
          };
      });
  });
```

I think "this.month_weekdays.push(wkday);" should push the string wkday to the array month_weekdays, so that for every value in the array days_in_month it should loop through weekdays and assign the string at index i%7 to index i of month_weekdays

So for the first value in days_in_month month_weekdays should look like:

MTWTFSSMTWTFSSMTWTFSSMTWTFSSMTW

(And because December has 31 days this should also be the final value of month_weekdays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem occurs because you use `function() {}` syntax without binding the `this`. Therefore `this.month_weekdays` doesn't exactly got the correct `month_weekdays`. There are two options:

1. Changing your function to arrow syntax, or
2. Bind `this` in your `function() {}`

**For option number one**, your code will look like this:

```
this.days_in_month.forEach((item) => {
  // console.log(item);
  item.forEach((value) => {
    // console.log(value);

    let thing: number = value;
      for(var i = 0; i < thing; i++) {
        let weekdays: string[] = [ 'M','T','W','T','F','S','S' ];
        let wkday: string = (weekdays[(i%7)]);
        this.month_weekdays.push(wkday);
      };
  });
```

});

You should be able to access your `month_weekdays` outside the loop. What happen is that `function() {}` syntax have its own `this`, therefore you have to bind the `this` from the outer scope so that the `function(){}` refers the correct `this`. On the other hand, arrow syntax is a shorter syntax than the `function(){}` and does not bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`; thus no binding of `this` is required.

**For option number two**, your code will look like this:

```
this.days_in_month.forEach(function(item) {
  // console.log(item);
  item.forEach(function(value) {
    // console.log(value);

    let thing: number = value;
      for(var i = 0; i < thing; i++) {
        let weekdays: string[] = [ 'M','T','W','T','F','S','S' ];
        let wkday: string = (weekdays[(i%7)]);
        this.month_weekdays.push(wkday);
      };
  }.bind(this));
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: This is awesome! I still don't understand what is going on with the arrow syntax tho?

Comment: @Davtho1983 `function() {}` syntax have its own `this`, therefore you have to bind the `this` from the outer scope so that the `function(){}` refers the correct `this`. While arrow syntax is a shorter syntax than the `function(){}` and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target; thus no binding of `this` required.. Reference about arrow syntax can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 3):

Works without the `this`:

```
const WEEK_DAYS: string[] = ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'];
var days_in_month = [
  [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
  [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
  [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
  [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
];

let month_weekdays = [];
days_in_month.forEach(item => {
  item.forEach(value => {
    for (var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
      let wkday: string = WEEK_DAYS[(i % 7)];
      month_weekdays.push(wkday);
    };
  });
});
```